# serve multiple .net core projects same server, subdomains

Tags: asp.net, nginx, nginx-config

i've spent this evening trying to configure Nginx to get subdomains to work, i have been unsuccessful, i don't know how i can get it to work, can someone please help

the scheme looks like this

```
"www.example.com" points to my .net core mvc project.     
"api1.example.com" points to my .net core api1 project.      
"api2.example.com" points to my .net core api2 project
```

my projects are listed like bellow in my linux server.

```
mvc /var/www/example.com   
api1 /var/www/api1.example.com  
api2 /var/www/api2.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out myself, i'll explain here how i got it to work.
in my original question i metionned two projects api1 and api2, in this solution i will only use one project api1 to make this short,

1- you need to register your sub domain in the A/AAAA record, you do this in your server provider dashboard, mine is "linode",
the record i added is "api1", you will also be asked to provide an ip address, it is the public IP of your server,

2- publish your project and copy the generated files to `/var/www/api1.example.com`
make sure the port is different from the mvc project.
for me mvc project port is 5000.
api1 project port is 5001.

3- create a service for your api1 project, the service file should be saved in the following directory `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-api1.service`

```js
[Unit]
Description=Example My ASP.NET Core Application running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/api1.example.com
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/api1.example.com/api1.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://127.0.0.1:5001

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4- add a new server block in the config file of your mvc project

```js
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name api1.example.com *.example.com;

  root /var/www/api1.example.com;

  index index.html index.htm;
       location / {
          proxy_pass  http://localhost:5001;    
       }
}
```

5- lastly don't forget to restart the new api1 service using this command in your SSH terminal.

```
sudo systemctl restart kestrel-api1.service
```

Also you need to restart Nginx using this command

```
service nginx restart
```

now if you navigate to example.com, the mvc project will be served.
if you navigate to api1.example.com it will serve api1 project.